# nginx service won't start after reboot + won't give output for service nginx status or start

Tags: ubuntu, nginx, amazon-ec2

A few weeks ago I configured an ec2 ubuntu server for my rails app.
everything worked great. 
the database is on RDS and I use nginx and passenger for the rails app. 
anyway everything worked great until my partner rebooted the server from the AWS console.
since then the nginx service is down.

I tried to restart it by running:

```
service nginx start
```

or

```
service nginx restart
```

I get no output for those commands.

If i run `ps aux | grep nginx`
I see that in fact the service isn't running.
checked the error logs, there wasn't an error since the day I installed the server.

please help

Comment: test the configuration `/usr/sbin/nginx -t` and then try to start directly `/usr/sbin/nginx`. Notice that after reboot public hostname of instance may have changed.

Comment: thanks for the comment. what do you mean public hostname changed? I parked a domain on the instance. and I have an elastic IP associated to it.

Comment: "Each time you stop and restart your Amazon EC2 instance (unless you are using an Elastic IP address), the public and private IP addresses change, and so does your public DNS name, system hostname, and shell prompt." http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/set-hostname.html

Comment: can you try initctl restart nginx ?

Comment: did you ever figure this out? I have the same issue on a customer server, and when it reboots nginx doesn't come up without my manual intervention which is really bad. it has happened twice this month and their site was unreachable for many hours each time :-(

Comment: @peedee hey man. it was a long time ago. but basically the problem was that this server had 2 installs of nginx on it. one on OPT and the other somewhere else. when the server rebooted it started the wrong one. or at least tried to.